# OpenGL: confused by the unproject function settings

Tags: c++, opengl, cursor, transform, raycasting

I need to implement raycasting. For this I need to convert the mouse cursor to world space.
I use the unproject function for this. I need to first find a point on the near plane, then on the far plane. After that, from the last substract the first one and we will get a ray.
But I don't understand how to set winZ correctly. Because in some implementations I see two ways: winZ = 0 (near plane), winZ = 1 (far plane) or winZ = -1 (near plane), winZ = 1 (far plane).
What's the difference in these ranges?

Answer (score 2):

If it really is *windows space* `z`, then there is only the `[0,1]` range. Note that 0 doesn't necessarily mean the near plane and one the far plane, though. One can set up a projection matrix where near will end up at 1 and far at 0 (reversed z, which, in combination with the `[0,1]` z clip condition as explained below, has some precision advantages).

Also not that `glDepthRange` can further modify to which values (inside `[0,1]`) these two planes will be mapped.

To understand the unproject operation, you first need to understand the different coordinate spaces. Typically in a render API, you have to deal with these 3 spaces at the *end* of the transform chain:

1. *clip space*: This is what the output of the vertex shader is in, and where the actual clipping at least on a conceptual level happens. This space is still homogeneous with an arbitrary value for the `w` coordinate.
2. *normalized device coordinates (NDC)*. This is what you get after the perspective division by the clip space `w` coordinate (*after* the clipping has been applied, which will eliminate the `w<=0` cases completely).
3. *window space*. The 2D `xy` part are the actual pixel coordinates inside your output window (or your render target), and the transformation from NDC `xy` to window space `xy` is defined by the viewport settings. The `z` coordinate is the value which will go into the depth test, and depth buffer, it is in the range `[0,1]` or some sub-range of that (controlled via `glDepthRange` in the GL).

Other spaces *before* these in this list, like model/object space, world space, eye/view space, are completely up to you and do not concern the GPU directly at all (legacy fixed-function GL did care about eye space for lighting and fog, but nowadays, implementing this is all your job, and you can use whatever spaces you see fit).

Having established the spaces, the next relevant thing here is the *viewing volume*. This is the volume of the space which will actually mapped to your viewport, and it is a 3D volume bounded by the six planes: left, right, bottom, top, near far.

However, the actual view volume is set up by pure *convention* in the various render APIs (and the actual GPU hardware).

Since you tagged this question with "OpenGL", I'm going to begin with the default GL convention first:

- Standard GL convention is the view volume is the completely symmetrical `[-1,1]` cube in NDC. Actually, this means that the *clip condition* in clip space is `-w <= x,y,z <= w`.
- Direct3D uses a different convention: they use `[-1,1]` in NDC for x and y just like GL does, but `[0,1]` for the z dimension. This also means that the depth range transformation into window space can be identity in many cases (you seldom need to limit it to a sub-range of [0,1]). This convention has some numerical advantages because the GL convention of moving `[-1,1]` range to `[0,1]` for window space will make it loose precision around the (NDC) zero point.
- Modern GL since GL 4.5 *optionally* allows you to switch to the `[0,1]` convention for z via `glClipControl`. Vulkan also supports both conventions, but  uses `[0,1]` as the default.

There is not "the" *unproject* function, but the concept of  "unprojecting" a point means calculating these transformations in reverse, going from window space back to some space before clip space, undoing the proejction matrix. For implementing an unproject function, you need to know which conventions were used.

> Because in some implementations I see two ways: winZ = 0 (near plane), winZ = 1 (far plane) or winZ = -1 (near plane), winZ = 1 (far plane). What's the difference in these ranges?

Maybe they are not taking in a window space Z, but NDC z directly. Maybe the parameters are just named in a confusing or wrong manner. Maybe some of the implementations out there are just flat-out *wrong*.

Comment: I still don't understand why 0 is near plane and 1 is far plane. What calculations is it based on?

Comment: The NDC and clip space postion of the clipping planes are defined _just by pure convention_. There is no calculation which leads to theses values. They are _defined_ by he specification. You can just choose between 2 z conventions in modern GL, as I have described. For window space, the `[0,1]` range is also a convention.